# JSF как создать пустой select без валидации

Tags: java, jsf

У меня возникла трудность с JSF. Суть в следующем:
Имеется такой код

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class WordBean implements Serializable {
    private String [] tags = new String[10];

    public String [] getTags() { return tags; }
    public void setTags(String [] tags) { this.tags = tags; }

    public void add() {
        System.out.println(tags);
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:selectManyMenu value="#{wordBean.tags}" styleClass="tags" immediate="true" />
        <h:commandButton action="#{wordBean.add}" value="Add" />
    </h:form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.tags').select2({tags: true});
    </script>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Select2 отрабатывает корректно, созаёт поле, для ввода новых тегов, но после отправки данных на сервер возникает ошибка "Validation Error: Value is not valid"
Я так понимаю, JSF пытается валидировать запрос и искать имеющиеся значения в select, разумеется не находит и выкидывает исключение.
Мне же нужно не валидировать это поле "tags", а принимать его, как новые параметры. Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне это сделать.
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Работа с `JSF` через `JavaScript` нередко создаёт трудно отлаживаемые ошибки. В большинстве случаев поставленные задачи можно решать без использования `JavaScript`. Опишите решаемую задачу, возможно в ответах предоставят грамотное её решение.
**PS** Похоже на то, что код страницы некорректен. Загрузка списка обычно осуществляется через `selectItem(s)`, а через `selectManyMenu` -> `value` передаётся выбранный пользователем элемент.

Comment: Никак. Эта встроенная валидация не убирается. Формируйте список тегов на сервере. Разве только если не попробовать написать свой renderer для компонента. Кроме всего прочего render как раз декодирует параметры запроса, выполняет всякие проверки, преобразование в данные приложения. Можно унаследовать родной рендер и переписать по своему декодирующую часть.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ваши ответы.
Задача собственно стояла такая. Нужно было дать возможность добавлять произвольные теги к записи. В конкретном примере, мне нужно было наполнять массив tags произвольными значениями. Изначально разумеется массив пустой.

Answer (score 1):

Снова хочу поблагодарить за ответы, они натолкнули меня на решение это задачи.
Суть в следующем:

## Создаём бин

```
@Named
@FacesConfig(version = JSF_2_3)
@SessionScoped
public class WordBean implements Serializable {
    private List<String> tags;
    private Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();

    public void setTags(List<String> tags) { this.tags = tags; }
    public void setOptions(Map<String, String> options) { this.options = options; }

    public List<String> getTags() { return tags; }
    public Map<String, String> getOptions() { return options; }

    public void add() {
        //Some login here
    }
}
```

## Создаём страницу

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Add tags</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:selectManyListbox value="#{wordBean.tags}" styleClass="tags" converter="wordConverter">
            <f:selectItems value="#{wordBean.options}" />
        </h:selectManyListbox>
        <h:commandButton action="#{wordBean.add}" value="Add" />
    </h:form>

    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.tags').select2({tags: true});
    </script>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Далее, так как у нас поле options пустое, и валидатор разумеется станет ругаться, потому, что не с чем сравнивать полученные теги созаём конвертор

```
@FacesConverter("wordConverter")
public class WordConverter implements Converter {
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String s) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        WordBean bean = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{wordBean}", WordBean.class);
        bean.getOptions().put(s, s);

        return s;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object o) {
        return o.toString();
    }
}
```

В этом случае конвертор вызывается до валидации бина, потому мы можем его немного модифицировать ;) путём обновления поля options бина

Конечно решение далеко от идеала возможно, я только начиная изучать jsf, но по крайней мере это решение выглядит более изящно, чем то, что было написано мной ранее ;)

Comment: Если для решения этой задачи существует более изящное решение, помогите пожалуйста с ответом )